# Getting AppGyver scanner to work in second PC emulator

Tags: android, steroids, appgyver

I have two machines. A) Ubuntu ; B ) Windows

I'm running steroids on system A and running genymotion with Google Services and AppGyver scanner. When connecting to A from B I get

"Error, please check that your network connection is working and try to scan again"

I assume this is because Oracle Virtualbox is using 192.168.56.x , while Steroids on A is running 192.168.1.x. Thus, they are not on the same network.

Is there a way to get this desired setup operational? Having it up on the big screen would really make things good for me.